# How to list all of Google Chrome TCP HTTP connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, google-chrome-extension, tcp

I need to see all of TCP connections of Google Chrome. Is it possible to log with Chrome Extension? How can I log all connections and see it on a webpage?

Use case: when I chat with people on ruletka.chat - I can see my strangers IP with Wireshark. How to store of IP adresses on a page with Chrome extension. Is it possible? Does Google Chrome API has that feature?

Comment: You can use `lsof` on Linux or MacOS. There's probably something analogous on Windows.

Comment: Extensions can't do that directly, but you can observe connectivity using chrome.webRequest API and infer which ones are still active from that.